# Opencart Custom Field at Checkout page

Tags: input, opencart-3

I added two input field on  View of checkout page.
But when I'm trying to get those input value to respect controller by using this code $this->input->post('myfield');
I'm not getting the value of that input field.

Does any one know how to get those input value?

Answer (score -1):

in corresponding controller file use: `$this->request->post['myfield'];` to get proper answer you must place your form code here.
No one has not the telepathic ability to guess what is wrong with your code.

Comment: So you should check your form. Can be there is the problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28859644)

Comment: @AtishAgrawal your comment does not provide any help to get an solution for the main question. My answer was what author need  to use by default in OC to get the posted data. Maybe author form is not correct. so he need to check it. Or place his form here to get an proper answer.